# How to find the highest and lowest product price

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Scala and have a DataFrame, I need to find the highest and lowest product prices for each category_id.

Top 20 rows of a dataframe is:

[image]

Please let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window operation for that, then it should be as below:

```
df.withColumn("rank", rank().over(Window.partitionBy("Category_id").orderBy($"price".desc)))
    .filter($"rank" <= 20)
    .drop("rank")
```

I hope, it will help you.

Comment: Hi getting the below error <console>:39: error: not found: value Window
       val df5 = df.withColumn("rank", rank().over(Window.partitionBy("category_id").orderBy($"price".desc))).filter($"rank" <=20).drop("rank")

Comment: you need import line `import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window`

Comment: Hi Ramesh, how to do the same without using spark SQL??

Comment: @DeepakPaul why would you want to do without spark SQL?